# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible occuring after switching to the same pop up window the second tiime

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to automate SearchFlights UseCase in Lufthamsa Airwyas site- URL - http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/ua/homepage.
Upon Clicking on the From link a pop up opens in which we have to select the origin country from a dropdown, based on the country vaklue,city dropdown will be loaded, and after selecting city, ccorresponding airport will be populated in the third dropdown. Then the focus has to be shifted to the main window and the To link has to be clicked, which again leads to the same popup window(with the same dropdows for the destination county>>city>>airport). Here is where I get the error. seems like WbDriver switches to the same poopup again, but its not able to find the elements on the page. This is really frustrating as it did the first time. My code is as below -

public class SearchFlights {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/ua/homepage");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    String main_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Main Window Handle: "+driver.getWindowHandle());
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#']/span[@class='airport-dir']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    for(String sub1_window : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(sub1_window);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl first']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-  country']/li[@data-value='IN']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-city']/li[@data-value='DEL']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl last']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-airport']/li[@data-value='DEL']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.switchTo().window(main_window);
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#'][@id ='aa-destination']/span[@class='airport-dir']")).click();
         Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.switchTo().window(sub1_window);
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
            System.out.println("Sub Window2 Handle: ");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl first']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-country']/li[@data-value='HK']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-city']/li[@data-value='IEV']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Select'][@href='#']/span")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl last']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-airport']/li[@data-value='KBP']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000L);*/
    }
     driver.switchTo().window(main_window);*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements you are trying to handle is not on the other window,it is on the same window.
Try This !

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/ua/homepage");
String main_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("aa-origin"));
from.click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl first']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-country']/li[@data-value='IN']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(2000L);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-city']/li[@data-value='DEL']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(2000L);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cl last']/ul[@class='aa-select aa-airport']/li[@data-value='DEL']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(2000L);
 WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("aa-destination"));
 to.click();
 Thread.sleep(3000L);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit_Dialog_1']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[@data-value='HK']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(3000L);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit_Dialog_1']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[@data-value='HKG']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(3000L);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit_Dialog_1']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/ul/li[@data-value='HKG']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(3000L);}
```

Comment: This is still not working, it is still getting stuck after clicking the to element, it gives element not visible. I am using chromedriver.. unable to run ff driver, as i have ff version 32 and looks to be incompatible with WD jar 2.42.2.. Please help.. Was this working for you

Comment: It worked when I replaced my xpath for the elements after to.click(),I tried yout xpath which seems to be the absolute xpath-

Comment: Why isn't this xpath valid as this was almost the same xpath used for From section elements-

Comment: That's the problem here, as the xpath for the both From an To elememts seems to be the same, so webdriver matches the xpath for the "To" element with the "From" element, and throws an error that element is not visible. And one thing about webdriver is it can only deal with the elements which is visible on the page.So when you click on the "To" element ,"To Airport" section become visible, at the same for the "From Airport" is also on the page ,but it is not visible.And yes ,this code is working for me !

Comment: This is working for me now after using the code which you have mentioned above

Comment: Anytime you can contact me !

Comment: Can I post a question and tag you in that so that you can post ur answers ? As I believe we cannot directly contact other users. My other query is related to the same website that I'm automating, SO I thought of somehow tagging you.. Is that possible?

Comment: I dont't think so. It is not possible.but u can contact me here ! just ping me . I will help you. shoaib_573@yahoo.co.in